# linked list insertion at end when header node is not null

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with inserting a node at the end of a linked list. It's not being executed when the start node is not null and I don't understand the problem. Please help me out here. The function is called second time but is not going to the else block.

```
typedef struct token_Info
{
    int linenumber;
    char* token;
    char value[200];
    struct token_Info* next;
} token_Info;

token_Info *tokenlist;

token_Info* insert_at_end( token_Info *list,char *name)
{
    printf("token identified \t");
    token_Info *new_node;
    token_Info *temp,*start;
    start = list ;
    char *tempname ;
    tempname = name;
    new_node= malloc(sizeof(token_Info));
    new_node->token = malloc(sizeof(strlen(tempname)+1));
    strcpy(new_node->token,tempname);
    new_node->next= NULL;
    // printf("%d",strlen(tempname));

    if(new_node == NULL){
        printf("nFailed to Allocate Memory");
    }

    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=new_node;
        return start;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("anvesh");
        temp = start;
        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp ->next;
        }
        temp->next = new_node;
        return temp;
    }
}

tokenlist = insert_at_end(tokenlist,"TK_BEGIN");
tokenlist = insert_at_end(tokenlist,"TK_BEGIN1");
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that the calls you have included here aren't accurate of what the code is actually doing?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I found two bugs, the first was the head of the list was not being returned when appending the list. The other in the memory allocation for the `token` string which incorrectly used `sizeof`.

I repositioned the test of the `malloc()` return value, and added a second one. I removed several unnecessary temporary variables that were cluttering the code. I added two functions, `show_list()` and `free_list()`. Finally, remember that the `value` string field is still uninitialised.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct token_Info
{
    int linenumber;
    char* token;
    char value[200];
    struct token_Info* next;
} token_Info;

token_Info* insert_at_end( token_Info *list, char *name)
{
    token_Info *new_node, *temp;
    new_node= malloc(sizeof(token_Info));
    if(new_node == NULL){                       // repositioned
        printf("\nFailed to allocate node memory\n");
        exit(1);                                // added
    }
    new_node->token = malloc(strlen(name)+1);   // removed sizeof
    if(new_node->token == NULL){                // added
        printf("\nFailed to allocate token memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(new_node->token, name);
    new_node->next= NULL;

    if(list==NULL)
        return new_node;

    // append
    temp = list;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = new_node;
    return list;                                // original head
}

void free_list( token_Info *list)
{
    token_Info *temp;
    while (list) {
        temp = list->next;
        free(list->token);
        free(list);
        list = temp;
    }
}

void show_list( token_Info *list)
{
    printf ("\nCurrent list:\n");
    while (list) {
        printf ("%s\n", list->token);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    token_Info *tokenlist = NULL;       

    tokenlist = insert_at_end(tokenlist, "TK_BEGIN");
    show_list(tokenlist);

    tokenlist = insert_at_end(tokenlist, "TK_SECOND");
    show_list(tokenlist);

    tokenlist = insert_at_end(tokenlist, "TK_FINAL");
    show_list(tokenlist);

    free_list(tokenlist);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Current list:
TK_BEGIN

Current list:
TK_BEGIN
TK_SECOND

Current list:
TK_BEGIN
TK_SECOND
TK_FINAL
```

Comment: I was also noticing that but apparently in the second call the printf does not show

Answer (score 0):

The question could also be whether you want `tokenlist` to be a running  end of the list, or remain at the start.

As of right now, your first call:
`tokenlist = insert_at_end(tokenlist,"TK_BEGIN");`
has `tokenlist` being the only node in the list.

The second call `tokenlist = insert_at_end(tokenlist,"TK_BEGIN1");` returns 'temp' which happens to also be the 'TK_BEGIN' node, ( ie, the first node )

If you want the return value to be the last element, you would return `new_node` instead of `temp`.  If you want to retain the start, you would return `start`;

All that said:

The calls to it are not part of any function,

I just ran it with the calls in `main` and got this output:

```
int main(void){
  tokenlist = insert_at_end(tokenlist,"TK_BEGIN");
  tokenlist = insert_at_end(tokenlist,"TK_BEGIN1");
  return 0;
}

$> ./a.out
token identified        token identified        anvesh
```